# Alert Dialog Not Showing Correct Text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i just created an alert dialog with multiple item. I set text in each items with values of string.xml but not showing corect value.

here is the code:

```
private void showImageImportDialog() {
    String[] items = new String[]{String.valueOf(R.string.open_camera), String.valueOf(R.string.open_gallery)};
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.select_image);
    dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0){
                ......

            }
            if (which == 1) {
                ......
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.create().show();
}
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="open_camera">Camera</string>
<string name="open_gallery">Gallery</string>
<string name="select_image">Select Image</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.valueOf(R.string.open_camera)` is not how to get a text from a resource id in Android.  You have to use `getString(R.string.open_camera)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Correct form to get string from xml is

```
getString(R.string.select_image)
```

example:

```
dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_image));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing many things wrong. First, you can declare your array in the string resources. I have rewrites your code to make it work.

Copy below code and paste it in your string resources file(e.g `res/string.xml`)

```
<string-array name="titles">
    <item>Camera</item>
    <item>Gallery</item>
    <item>Select Image</item>
</string-array>
```

Then, replace your java code with the following.

```
  private void showImageImportDialog() {
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(items[2]);
        dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        dialog.create().show();
    }
```

It should work now.